# Flask: own login_required decorator does not redirect

Tags: redirect, flask, decorator, login-required

I have used te decorator shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22414887/4367554) and adapted it to my needs (multiple roles)
The decorator checks the roles and tells me if I'm not authorized but it does not redirect me to my login page as the original decorator does.

```
def login_required(role="ANY"):
    def wrapper(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
            if not current_user.is_authenticated():
                return lm.unauthorized()
            if ((role not in current_user.roles) and (role != "ANY")):
                return lm.unauthorized()
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_view
    return wrapper
```

Ok here is the original decorator from flask-login:

```
def login_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if current_app.login_manager._login_disabled:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        elif not current_user.is_authenticated():
            return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code says abosolulty nothing, which is a shame, in all cases it just runs `lm.unauthorized()`, But why are you not using [redirect](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.redirect)? Hope it hels a bit ;)

Comment: When I check the decorator function of the original flask-login.py then there is also no redirect included. It seems to be handled in the unauthorized function.

Comment: Then maybe you should post that one.. doh

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the redirect worked properly - it was only an issue within my view.py.

I hope you will at least find my role-adaptation a little helpful!